# Stopping Decimal Truncation in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, excel

How can I stop a decimal from being truncated in Visual Basic, and keep it as a full decimal rather than a truncated number in scientific notation?

I have this little bit of code from am Excel Macro that I'm modifying for someone (only the Debug.Print statements are mine):

```
rttime = asht.Cells(i, timecol).Value
Debug.Print "rttime=" & rttime
Debug.Print "To string: " & CStr(CDec(rttime))
rtdelta = rttime - wavonset_value 'searchcol="AOISlide2"
Debug.Print "rtdelta=" & rtdelta
```

The Debug.Print statements give me:

```
rttime=1.343301E+12
To string: 1343301000000
rtdelta=0
```

So basically what is happening here is the values are being pulled from the Excel Worksheet in scientific notation, and everything not shown in that notation is getting truncated.

The actual number should be **1343300687515.39**, but it is being forced down to **1.343301E+12**, and even if I force it out of scientific notation, it's still giving me **1343301000000**.

How can I get it to be the actual number with decimal points and all? This aspect is practically required because in some instances, there might only be a difference of 20 or so, but since it's truncating to the millions place, it's completely useless.

Edit: Here's the entire function for reference

```
Function GetAOIRowStart(asht As Worksheet, startrow&, endrow&, searchstr$, searchcol&, 

AOItime_start As Single) As Long
Dim i&
Dim rtdelta As Single
Dim rttime As Single
Dim wavonset_value As Single
Dim timecol&


timecol = 4
wavonset_value = asht.Cells(startrow, timecol).Value 'tettime
Debug.Print "wavonset_value=" & wavonset_value

i = startrow
Do Until i >= endrow

    'scan down TeTTime' column to find nearest look of interest
    rttime = asht.Cells(i, timecol).Value
    Debug.Print "rttime=" & rttime
    Debug.Print "To string: " & CStr(CDec(rttime))
    rtdelta = CDec(Right(rttime, 9)) - CDec(Right(wavonset_value, 9)) 'searchcol="AOISlide2"
    Debug.Print "rtdelta=" & rtdelta
    If rtdelta >= AOItime_start Then
         Exit Do
    End If


    i = i + 1
Loop

GetAOIRowStart = i
'Debug.Print asht.Cells(i, sound_playing_col).Value
End Function
```

Comment: I think it has to do with the numerical precision of Excel (which is not very good, by the way)... Very big (or very small) numbers in Excel are truncated

Comment: @Barranka I actually have the spreadsheet set to not truncate the numbers. In the spreadsheet, it shows the entire number, decimals and all.

Comment: which is the type of `rttime`? (I'm trying to reproduce the situation)

Comment: All three numbered variables are Singles.

Comment: Declare them as Double.

Comment: @SiddharthRout That appears to have fixed it. This really is a god-awful piece of code that I'm inheriting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has to do with the size of the variable. If `rttime` is `Single`, which is not big enough to hold the data you need. Changing the variable type to `Double` should fix the problem.

As a thumb rule, unless you have very tight memory constraints, use `Long` to hold integer values and `Double` to hold floating-point values. Reserve the `Decimal` type for very precise calculations. I also suggest you avoid `Variant` types.

Comment: Thanks! We also had figured this out in the comments last night. I'm inheriting this code from someone who no longer works in our lab and I'm just making modifications, but there are some pretty bad practices used in here.